# Create new column based on pattern in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, data-wrangling, mutate

I have the following data frame in R out of which I'd like to create a new column containing the Nut for each municipal (See second table). "Nut" refers simply to a higher hirachy level of municipalities in portugal. For later analysis I need to group the data by Nuts. The entire dataframe consists of 308 municipalities and 25 Nuts.

Does someone have a suggestion on how to approach this task? Since the number of municipals in each Nut differes I have difficulties on where to begin.

| geo-group | nuts_municipal |
| --- | --- |
| Nut III | Alto Minho |
| Municipal | Arcos de Valdevez |
| Municipal | Caminha |
| Municipal | Monção |
| Municipal | Ponte da Barca |
| Nuts III | Ponte da Barca |
| Municipal | Amares |
| Municipal | Barcelos |
| Municipal | Braga |
| Nuts III | Fafe |
| Municipal | Ave |

This is what I'd like to have as a final result.

| geo-group | nuts_municipal | Nut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nut III | Alto Minho |  |
| Municipal | Arcos de Valdevez | Alto Minho |
| Municipal | Caminha | Alto Minho |
| Municipal | Monção | Alto Minho |
| Municipal | Ponte da Barca | Alto Minho |
| Nut III | Cávado |  |
| Municipal | Amares | Cávado |
| Municipal | Barcelos | Cávado |
| Municipal | Braga | Cávado |
| Nut III | Ave |  |
| Municipal | Fafe | Ave |
| Municipal | Mondim de Basto | Ave |

I have difficulties on where to begin and so far haven't found any appreach.

Answer (score 2):

You can `group_by` Nuts III and then use `first`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(gp = cumsum(`geo-group` == "Nuts III")) %>% 
  mutate(Nut = ifelse(row_number() == 1, "", first(nuts_municipal)))
```

Comment: I think a regex, e.g. `group_by(gp = cumsum(grepl("Nut", `geo-group`)))`, is more robust as for the first group we have `"Nut III".

Comment: True, although i assumed this was a typo

Answer (score 2):

A second option would be to use `tidyr::fill` and `if_else`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat |> 
  mutate(Nut = if_else(grepl("^Nut", `geo-group`), nuts_municipal, NA_character_)) |> 
  tidyr::fill(Nut) |> 
  mutate(Nut = if_else(grepl("^Nut", `geo-group`), "", Nut))
#>    geo-group    nuts_municipal            Nut
#> 1    Nut III        Alto Minho               
#> 2  Municipal Arcos de Valdevez     Alto Minho
#> 3  Municipal           Caminha     Alto Minho
#> 4  Municipal            Monção     Alto Minho
#> 5  Municipal    Ponte da Barca     Alto Minho
#> 6   Nuts III    Ponte da Barca               
#> 7  Municipal            Amares Ponte da Barca
#> 8  Municipal          Barcelos Ponte da Barca
#> 9  Municipal             Braga Ponte da Barca
#> 10  Nuts III              Fafe               
#> 11 Municipal               Ave           Fafe
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
       check.names = FALSE,
       `geo-group` = c("Nut III","Municipal",
                       "Municipal","Municipal","Municipal","Nuts III","Municipal",
                       "Municipal","Municipal","Nuts III","Municipal"),
    nuts_municipal = c("Alto Minho",
                       "Arcos de Valdevez","Caminha","Monção","Ponte da Barca",
                       "Ponte da Barca","Amares","Barcelos","Braga","Fafe","Ave")
)
```